# ¿Cómo obtener listado tabla pivote desde otra tabla?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Quiero obtener la cantidad de **estudiantes** por un **curso** desde un modelo llamado `AsistenciaxCursos` que contiene los cursos dentro de él a traves de una relación con modelo `Curso` usando un campo llamado **curso_id**. El modelo `Matriculas` contiene cursos enlanzandose con el model `Curso` a traves de **curso_id**. Las **matriculas** contienen estudiantes pero los modelos(`Matriculas`, `Estudiantes`) se comunican con una tabla pivot llamada `Matriculas_Estudiantes`.

**Modelo AsistenciaxCursos**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AsistenciaxCurso extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [ 'fecha_inicio', 'fecha_final', 'curso_id', 'asistencia', 'ausencia', 'total_estudiante' ];

    public function curso() {
        return $this->belongsTo( Curso::class, 'curso_id' );
    }

}
```

**Modelo Cursos**

```
<?php
    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Curso extends Model {
        protected $fillable = [ 'curso', 'numero', 'costo', 'semestre_id', 'descripcion' ];

        public function matricula() {
            return $this->hasMany( Matricula::class, 'curso_id' );
        }

        public function asistencia() {
            return $this->hasMany( AsistenciaxCurso::class, 'curso_id' );
        }
    }
```

**Modelo Matriculas**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Matricula extends Model {


    protected $fillable = [ 'folio', 'tomo', 'num_matricula', 'observ', 'curso_id', 'profesor_id' ];



    public function curso() {
        return $this->belongsTo( Curso::class, 'curso_id' );
    }

    public function estudiante() {
        return $this->belongsToMany( Estudiante::class );
    }
```

}

**Modelo Estudiantes**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Estudiante extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [
        'num_cliente',
        'nombre',
        'apellidos',
        'ci',
        'lugar_de_nacimiento',
        'sexo_id',
        'direccion',
        'municipio_nacimiento_id',
        'provincia_nacimiento_id',
        'telefono',
        'grado_id',
        'centro_estudio_id',
        'anodexpe',
        'organismo_id',
        'cargo_id',
        'direccion_d_trabajo',
        'municipio_trabajo_id',
        'provincia_trabajo_id',
    ];


    public function matricula() {
        return $this->hasMany( Matricula::class, 'matricula_id' );
    }

}
```

*La tabla pivot se llama Matricula_Estudiantes y contiene matricula_id y estudiante_id*

En el `AsistenciaxCursoController` donde en el metodo **store** captura la cantidad de estudiantes para almacenar en el campo **total_estudiante** del modelo `AsistenciaxCurso`.

**Controller AsistenciaxCursoController**

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\AsistenciaxCurso;
    use App\Curso;
    use App\Matricula;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Validator;

    class AsistenciaxCursoController extends Controller {
     //...
        /**
         * Show the form for creating a new resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function create() {

            return view( 'Secretaria.Asistencia.create', [ 'cursos' => Curso::all() ] );
        }
/**
         * Store a newly created resource in storage.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function store( Request $request ) {
            $validate = Validator::make( $request->all(), [
                'fecha_inicio' => 'required|date',
                'fecha_final'  => 'required|date',
                'curso_id'     => 'required',
                'asistencia'   => 'required|integer',
                'ausencia'     => 'required|integer',
            ] );
            if ( $validate->fails() ) {
                return [ 'success' => false, 'errors' => $validate->errors() ];
            }
            $asistencia               = new AsistenciaxCurso();
            $asistencia->fecha_inicio = $request->has( 'fecha_inicio' );
            $asistencia->fecha_final  = $request->has( 'fecha_final' );
            $asistencia->curso_id     = $request->has( 'curso_id' );
            $asistencia->asistencia   = $request->has( 'asistencia' );
            $asistencia->ausencia     = $request->has( 'ausencia' );
            $temp                     = Matricula::have( 'curso_id', '=', $request->has( 'curso_id' ) )
                                                 ->get();

            $asistencia->total_estudiante = count( $temp->estudiante);

            if ( $asistencia->save() ) {
                return [
                    'success' => true,
                    'message' => '¡Satisfactorio!, Asistencia: ' . $asistencia->curso->curso . ', creado con exito.',
                ];

            } else {
                return [
                    'success' => false,
                    'message' => '¡Error!, No se pudo insertar la asistencia. Intente mas tarde.',
                ];
            }


        }
```

Como obtengo dicha *cantidad de estudiantes* en una variable usando **Eloquent**. Saludos de antemano.

Comment: Bueno, la verdad es que la descripción del problema parece un trabalenguas. ¿De dónde sale el valor que buscas?

Comment: El valor sale de la tabla pivot Matriculas_Estudiantes y tengo q contarlos en AsistenciasxCursos

Answer (score 1):

Prueba añadiendo en **Modelo Estudiantes**:

```
public function cursos () {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Curso::class, Matricula::class)->withPivot(['asistencia']);
}
```

Después lo puedes llamar:

```
$student = Estudiante::find($student_id)->with(['cursos'])->get();
```